# unix shell script - compare 2 files .. file1 has 2 colmns(emp id) and emp_sal) an d file 2 has 2 columns (emp_id) and emp_sal

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I need to compare if each `emp_id` in `file1` is present in `file2` and for that `emp_id` then I need to compare whether the `emp_sal` in `file1` and `file2` is matching for that `emp_id`. Similar way I have to compare all `emp_ids` in `file1` with `file2` and return the output matching in one file and not matching in another file.

File1

```
Emp-id emp-sal
1234.     1200
1255.     1400
4567.      5800
8765.      2340
```

File2

```
Emp-num. Emp-sal- amt
1234.   1200
1255.    1700
4567.   5800
8765.   2340
```

Output matching record

```
Emp-id emp-sal emp- sal-amt
1234.    1200.     1200 
4567.     5800.    5800
8765.      2340.    2340
```

Not matching

```
Emp-id emp-sal emp-sal-amt
1255.    1400.     1700
```

Comment: Could you please add examples of both files and the expected output. And please add the information from the title to the question edit the title to be a bit more generic.

Comment: Also please show us what have you tried so far to solve your problem.

Comment: While waiting for examples, this one is a way to do it in bash: `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

Comment: Shell script is pretty powerfull tool, but what you presented is much more a database task.

Comment: It would help if you show some more detail about what the files look like, what the expected output is. Also what your tried, and what was wrong with that.

Comment: Hi Kumar. Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask -- it will help explain the largely negative reaction to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Matching case:

```
join <(< File1 sed '1d; s/  */ /g' | sort -n -k1,1) \
     <(< File2 sed '1d; s/  */ /g' | sort -n -k1,1) | awk '$2==$3'
```

`join` needs fields delimited by a single character (a blank by default) and the lines must be sorted by the key field (the first one by default), so I added a bit of `sed` to clean up the input: `'1d;` will skip the headers, and `s/  */ /g'` replaces multiple blanks with a single one.